# ActiveMQ/Camel send file for further processing

Tags: web-services, activemq-classic, apache-camel

So I got my ActiveMQ to receive messages from another location woo hoo - happy dance going on here this morning!

Now I need to take subsequent steps on the messages once they arrive in the queue.

Specifically, depending on the file name, it will need to be sent to another queue or directly to another process if that can happen.

For instance, a one file is sent that contains information about changes to a court session.  I need to read that XML and update some local  MySQL tables.  Could the court session process be a webservice? ideally I would like to just pass along the file to that service.

Another file is sent that contains information about a cancelled warrant, I need to send information from that file to a stored procedured on an external Oracle database.
I can tell from the file name what the next process is that the file should be sent to.

So, I am looking for suggestions on what would my best course of action is to set up the additional processing for the files that are being sent to our queue?

Thanks a bunch!!!
BTW - We have already ordered 'ActiveMQ in Action' and 'Camel in Action' and I will be reading those but for right now, any specific newbie guidance will be greatly appreciated.

leslie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Camel's [content based router](http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html) is what you are looking for.  It allows you to setup routing rules based on the message body/headers/properties...

Here is a basic example that reads from an inbound queue and simply delegates to other queues based on headers...

```
   from("activemq:queue:inboundQueue")
        .choice()
            .when(header("foo").isEqualTo("bar"))
                .to("activemq:queue:barQueue")
            .when(header("foo").isEqualTo("cheese"))
                .to("activemq:queue:cheeseQueue")
            .otherwise()
                .to("activemq:queue:generalQueue");
```

In addition to checking message headers, you can also check the body and properties (using [simple](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) expressions, [xpath](http://camel.apache.org/xpath.html), etc) to determine proper routing, etc...

Comment: Ok I have the spring XML set up but I want to see if the file name contains the expression TAHEARING~SAVE-COURTSESSION - can you help me with the xPath I would need for that?  And when you say header foo - where is that set up?  I see in the message that there is header information, would I replace foo with one of the values from that list?  Thanks!

Comment: Leslie, you can change "foo" to reference any header property...post your XML message and I can try to help with the xpath...

Comment: I ended up using the <choice> tag with <simple>${file:name} contains 'TA...'</simple> and that seems to be working ok...but back to what you said about the properties, do you mean the message properties that I can see from the ActiveMQ Admin console?  Additionally, when i am looking at that console view of the message, I do not see anything in the Message Details.  Is the original XML still in the message somewhere?